# The service myService on local computer stared an then stopped automatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

i did set start my windows service or NT service like everybody says a then 
came up this message:

The  service myService on local computer started an then stopped.Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by another services or programs

i've started other services and it never hapened...
before  i change the value of a parameter that have to find it's value on a web service method
that look on a sql database...

and other change is that got formatted the hard disk...maybe i have to enable somethig
please i need help

Comment: Is this a service you have written (then we would like some code) or a windows or 3rd party service (then you need to be at ServerFault or SuperUser)?

Comment: If you wrote the service yourself, the OnStart method is especially interessting. Please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

It happens most likely because
you have an exception at startup... try to debug your things either by
using a log or by trying to reproduce your behavior in a windows app....

You can even debug your windows service using the following method...

Write the following code in your Service file...

```
public void OnDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}
```

In the program file,

```
YourService myService = new YourService();
myService.OnDebug();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the logic performed using a windows service exceeds the default timeout.

We cannot overcome the default timeout of a windows service. Usually windows services are used to instantiate a method. So start a child thread within the OnStart event of the windows service and call your method within it.

If this is not solving your issue, put the code in try catch and log the exceptions. This error can happen if there is any exception within OnStart event too.